# mySqlTrigger altering the same table it exist

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table

```
CREATE  TABLE `accounting`.`Foo` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `This` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `That` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `The_Other` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Times_altered` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );
```

I wish to have a trigger simply count the under of times that this record is altered.  My 'DBA' is telling me that I cannot alter the table I am in in Mysql with a trigger as it will cause a 'loop'.

I am not a SQL guy:  but something tells me I need a new DBA.

Is this in fact true?

Cant I simply increment the   `Times_altered` INT NULL ?

Comment: Negative feedback is still better and more polite than no feedback at all, you know? After all we invest time and work into trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE `accounting`.`Foo` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `This` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `That` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `The_Other` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Times_altered` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

CREATE  TABLE `accounting`.`logs` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `table` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `update_count` int NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

CREATE TRIGGER `update_counter` UPDATE ON `Foo`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO logs SET update_count = update_count + 1 WHERE table = 'Foo';
END;
```

Note: code above isn't tested. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is indeed not the right choice. A trigger in MySQL gets activated for each row affected by your update statement, which means if you update 10 rows, the Times_altered column in your design gets updated 10 times. And should the same value in Times_altered be in all rows of the table or just in one? Either way not the best design in my opinion.

Now you could have a second table like in cetver's answer. Again updating is not an option, cause it would produce wrong results. That's why he's inserting. Then you'd have for each table multiple rows and you'd have to query the maximum value...But note, it may still be the wrong result, depending on if you want to count if the table's rows were altered one time with one statement, or how much rows were affected.

I would suggest, either you do it like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE `accounting`.`Foo` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `This` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `That` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `The_Other` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

CREATE  TABLE `accounting`.`logs` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `table` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `update_count` int NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ-COMMITED;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Foo SET whatever = whatever;
UPDATE logs SET update_count = update_count + 1 WHERE table = 'Foo';
COMMIT;
```

Why the transaction? It's to make the process concurrency safe.

Or you use a stored procedure (something like this):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_update (IN stmt varchar(1000), IN tablename varchar(100))
BEGIN
SET @sql = stmt;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE logs SET update_count = update_count + 1 WHERE table = ', tablename, ';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you'd use the procedure like this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ-COMMITED;
START TRANSACTION;
CALL my_update('UPDATE Foo SET whatever = whatever', 'Foo');
COMMIT;
```

Or you put the `start transaction` into the procedure.